# Как правильно задать background input?

Tags: html, css, sass

Верстаю, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть header с overlay, на нем заголовок, текст и форма. Причем форма имеет полупрозрачную подложку, а инпуты черный background. Так вот все сделал, но input полупрозрачный как подложка,да и текст не совсем белый как здесь быть? Как это можно исправить? Пробовал через z-index, результата не дало. Думаю может через абсолютное позиционирование?
Посмотреть все можно [здесь](http://martynuk.esy.es/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас для `.overlay` установлено свойство `opacity`:

```
header .overlay {
    opacity: .7;
}
```

В таком случаи, все что находится внутри него также будет прозрачным. Исправить можно следующим образом, удалить это свойство `opacity`, а `background` задать в формате `rgba`:

```
header .overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 10, 15, .7);
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, завтыкал.

Comment: @zorro, Бывает) Как вариант, можно `.overlay` сделать отдельным, абсолютным блоком и растянуть на всю ширину хедера.

Answer (score 1):

У вас верхний слой overlay имеет параметр `opacity: 0.7` - если его отключить, то подобных проблем с дочерней прозрачность не будет. Попробуйте добиться желаемого результата через прозрачность в `rgba()`, например.

Цвет текста корректируется через вендорные префиксы  - по-умолчанию, у него стоит прозрачность.

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder    { opacity: 1 }
::-moz-placeholder                  { opacity: 1 }
:-ms-input-placeholder              { opacity: 1 }
```